# Fetching data from sqlite database - ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have 5 records in my database table, I need the fourth record to be display in `NSLog`, but its not going into `IF` statement of the code. Can someone suggest where I am wrong?

Here is my code.

```
-(void) readFromDatabase {

    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;


    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from QuestionAnswers where Q.No = 4";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // Read the data from the result row

                NSString *questions = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *answers = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                NSLog(@"Questions:%@",questions);
                NSLog(@"Answers:%@",answers);


            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which if statement ? are you sure that 1) the database is present in the databasePath ? 2) databasePath is not nil ? 3) database contains the needed data ?

Comment: check your nslog getting data or not log it..

Comment: check your database path . if database path is correct , then check your table name and query

Comment: @MidhunMP in my second if statement ie. here if(sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

Comment: @Akshea: Check whether the `QuestionAnswers` table exist in the database.

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes i have checked it. Spellings everything, and the table exist in the database.

Comment: Remove application from simulator and run agian.

Comment: @MidhunMP,@Viruss mca When i give where condition in my query, this problem occurs. If i dint mention any where condition, it goes into IF statement.So, how to query it.

Comment: @Akshea: probably there will be no column like: `Q.No` Check the name

Answer (score 0):

are you getting database from `document` folder? If yes, then check before executing the code whether the `database` is well copied into Document folder or not.

```
- (BOOL) getFileExistence: (NSString *) filename
{
    BOOL IsFileExists = NO;

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *favsFilePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:favsFilePath])
    {
        IsFileExists = YES;
    }
    return IsFileExists;
}

BOOL isDBExists = [self getFileExistence:@"dbname"];
```

Comment: Yes database is present in databasePath..i have checked it...in IF prepared statement its not going after below line if(sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

Comment: When i give where condition in my query, this problem occurs. If i dint mention any where condition, it goes into IF statement.So, how to query it

Comment: then open the db manually and check if that is not currupted.